# join few regex patterns (not some str, any words, date)

Tags: php, regex

I got three working regex patterns:

```
^(sezon\s[0-9]+)  => finds if string starts with sezon $$ where $is digit
([a-zA-z]*|\b)*.* => that should match any words 
\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{2,4} => that matches date
```

Now I want to negate first and third pattern and join them into second.

```
Sezon 2 some text here 03.02.1203 => should be excluded
Sezon more text => included
Sezon 2 mote set amet => excluded
some date here 20.20.2222 =>excluded
only text here also => included
   2 - => excluded
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to deny strings with:

- date at the end,
- Sezon $ at the beginning
- 1 - at the beginning

Rest (Sezon some text) (only text) should be accepted

Now I can make 3 preg_matches and then combine theirs outputs in 'if' but I was wondering if it can be done in one pattern. Or maybe different idea entirely?

Real string which will be used:
    sezon 1

```
    1 - 
    Pilot (pilot)
    26.10.2015

2 - 
Stronger Together
2.11.2015
3 - 
Fight or Flight
9.11.2015
```

Lines are broken by explode function.
For each line string I want to check if its Season, number, title or date and then do different stuff in each case.

Comment: The second pattern is totally wrong since it matches any string.

Comment: I would say that Pattern 2 can be reduced to `.*`.

Comment: It should match any text string between other stuff. Thats why I mean to merge three patterns to one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
'~^(?!\h*\d+\h*-‌|sezon\h+[0-9]+|.*\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{2,4}$).+~im'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6OMr5e/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\h*\d+\h*-‌|sezon\h+[0-9]+|.*\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{2,4}$)` - a negative lookahead that will fail the match if a string starts with 0+ horizontal whitespaces, 1+ digits, 0+ whitespaces and `-` (see `\h*\d+\h*-‌`)  or starts with `sezon`, 1+ whitespaces and 1+ digits, or (`|`) ends with the `\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{2,4}` pattern (as there must be the end of string after it - `$`)
- `.+` - 1 or more chars other than line break chars.

Comment: Updated question. One more thing came up before I could test

Comment: Does that mean you have a string with multiple linebreaks and records you want to extract?

Comment: Almost. Just one more exclusion: those of "    1 - ". any whitespace char

Comment: Ok, try `^(?!sezon\s+[0-9]+|.*\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{2,4}$|\h*\d+\h*-).+`, see https://regex101.com/r/6OMr5e/3

Comment: Yes, that does the job. I thought adding ^ will negate but I was wrong. Please update your original answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated it. Note it should even work with an unexploded string.